# SyntaxError: invalid syntax while building a dict from a list using Python 2.6

Tags: python

I created a Python script with Python2.7 and it works fine. However, when I run the same script with Python2.6, I got a "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" error.

After investigating, the problem seems to be related to a for loop.

```
l1 = [["a1", "a2"], ["b1", "b2"]]
print {item[0]:item[1] for item in l1}
```

When I run the above code with Python 2.7, I've got the following output:

```
{'a1': 'a2', 'b1': 'b2'}
```

When I run the same code with Python 2.6, I've got the following error:

```
>>> l1 = [["a1", "a2"], ["b1", "b2"]]
>>> print {item[0]:item[1] for item in l1}
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print {item[0]:item[1] for item in l1}
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Regards,
Allen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
print dict(item for item in l1)
```

**Edit about your comment:** If you want to explicitly select items, wrap them in a tuple:

```
print dict((item[1], item[4]) for item in l1)
```

Comment: Thanks Space_C0wb0y and your code works. However, in my question I've simplified the code. There are actually more than 2 elements in each sublist in l1.  I would like to do something like "print dict(item[1]:item[4] for item in l1)" and it's still giving me an error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thank you very much Space_C0wb0y, the updated version works perfect! I've spent half an hour in debugging it and it only took you 2 minutes to fix it. I still have a lot to learn. :-(

Answer (score 3):

Dictionary comprehensions aren't available in Python 2.6. See [Space_C0wb0y's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110970/syntaxerror-invalid-syntax-while-building-a-dict-from-a-list-using-python-2-6/6110988#6110988) for how to get around that in code.

Comment: But why are they in 2.7? [The PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) was withdrawn, and I always thought it was a Python 3 feature.

Comment: Not sure why either, but they eventually got [backported from 3.1](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.7.html).

Comment: Thank you guys, the solution provided by Space_C0wb0y works fine.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
print dict([tuple(i) for i in l1])
```

Comment: This seems a little complicated. There is no need to build a list of tuples first.